# tableView footer strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

**Given**: I have a bit of a "pop up" view that I put over my tableView within my UITableViewController.  I put it there like this:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.hoverView];
```

**Problem**: I cannot see this hoverView when I add a tableView footer view.  Seemingly unrelated yes?

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:someLabel];
```

These appear to be mutually exclusive.  I can have one, but not the other.  To see what's going on, I print subview descriptions like so:

```
for (UIView *sub in self.navigationController.view.subviews)
{
    NSLog([sub description]);
}
```

When the table footer view is added, this code prints nothing.  Otherwise, I see the expected output of some navigationController internal views.  What did I miss?!

Comment: is it possible that when you add the tableView footer view, the hover view is being added below the footer view.  Also, you should know that you are leaking memory in your second code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the hoverView to the UINavigationController's view. Instead of using a UITableViewController, use a UIViewController whose view contains a UITableView as a subview. (See [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html) for details of how to implement the rest of the UITableViewController's functionality in your UIViewController). Then add your hoverView to that view, i.e., make it a sibling of the UITableView, but a later sibling so it appears above it.

This may not solve your problem but I'd say it's your best bet: a UINavigationController is not designed to have its view manipulated directly, it's designed to have view controllers pushed onto its stack and add subviews to its view accordingly.